# How do I make only numbers that can be typed into input?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script>
function lettersOnly(input) {
var regex = /[^a-z]/gi;
input.value = input.value.replace(regex, "");
}
</script>

<input type="tel" name="Contact number" pattern="\d{8}" title='8 digits telephone number' placeholder=" Contact Number" id="contactno"
            onkeyup="lettersOnly(this)"><br>
```

The input section is part of a form and I want to make sure only numbers can be typed into the contact number input.

Comment: Use `<input type='number'>`

Comment: Is this a question or the answer?

Comment: Its a question, not answer

Comment: @AungThuraZaw Check out the dupe. Please search before posting.

Comment: Look, I am just a student, alright, so I am really bad, I am just needing help so forgive me if I am not smart

Comment: @PraveenKumar Note, duplicate Answer provides jQuery solution where neither original Question nor present Question includes jQuery tags. Note also that duplicate Answer also allows non-digit to be input and displayed before removing non-digit character

Comment: @AungThuraZaw Okay, you are not that bad. LoL. No one said you bad, but please do a search. That's what is the request.

Comment: For phone numbers it's a *terrible* idea to restrict input to only numeric characters. How would someone indicate an extension? How would someone indicate that `#` must be used? You're asking for generally 10 digits to be entered, and the user can't even include a space or hyphen to make it easier to verify that they input their number correctly? The general answer is to strip the unnecessary characters *after* the user has submitted the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `oninput` event, `RegExp` `/\D/` to check if input is not a digit character, `String.prototype.replace()`; if typed character is not a digit set `.value` to characters before non-digit

```js
document.querySelector("input")
.oninput = function(e) {
  e.target.value = e.target.value.replace(/\D/g, "")
}
```

```html
<input type="text" />
```

Comment: better, in fact this could be easier than my idea, just remove the test part